# Hide Div Based on Great-grandchild javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to hide a Div with class of faq-cat based on its great-grandchild has class of empty. If possible I would like to use a little javascript. I have provided a sample of the HTML.

```
<div class="faq-cat">
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <div class="vend-list">
    <div id="wpv-view-layout-275-TCPID281CTID23" class="js-wpv-view-layout">
      <div class="empty">No items found</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide parent element with onclick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399897/hide-parent-element-with-onclick-function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a parent div if an inner div has a certain class, with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318676/how-to-hide-a-parent-div-if-an-inner-div-has-a-certain-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you can find all `faq-cat` elements on a page first. Then you select first one (works if you have only one of those on a page, if more you need to loop through the `cats` NodeList). Then you search for a child with `empty` class inside this `faq-cat` element, if at least one element with `empty` class is found - hide the `faq-cat`.

```
const cats = document.getElementsByClassName('faq-cat')
const cat = cats[0];
const empties = cat.getElementsByClassName('empty')
if (empties.length) cat.classList.add("hidden");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This answer is really only a partial answer, since it doesn't make it explicit how it can be integrated with the OP's code.  It would also benefit from a description of how it is meant to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery, then

```
$(".faq-cat").find($(".vend-list")).find($(".js-wpv-view-layout")).find($(".empty")).length
```

if length is 0, then element doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

Before answering I would like you to reconsider if you really need/want JavaScript to solve this. For example what happens if the user has JavaScript disabled? And the user will probably see [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) while the page loads and the JavaScript is fired.

**Are you using a framework?** If you have control over how the template is generated you might want to prevent the content from being rendered instead of hiding it in the frontend, e.g. using server-side template logic:

```
<%= Enum.any? @cats do %>
  <div class="faq-cat">...</div>
<% end %>
```

(example using [phoenix](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix) framework)

If you don't have any control over the template before it's served to the user, you could try something like this in JavaScript:

```js
var fagCat = document.querySelector(".faq-cat");

if (fagCat.querySelector(".empty")) {
  fagCat.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
Below is a hidden empty faq-cat div:

<div class="faq-cat">
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <div class="vend-list">
    <div id="wpv-view-layout-275-TCPID281CTID23" class="js-wpv-view-layout">
      <div class="empty">No items found</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is built using Wordpress and Toolset. The issue is that I am using two taxonomies and while the category may be empty under one taxonomy it is not empty under the other. So when it checks to see it it is empty it is not, but then there is still nothing to display.